# Play+Scala suite test not found type PlaySpecification

Tags: scala, testing, playframework, sbt

It is my first web app using Play Framework and Scala. I am following this tutorial > https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-integration-tests-to-a-play-framework-application-using-scala and after the app working well, my tests cannot work. When I type sbt test the compiler says cannot find PlaySpecification.

```
[error] /home/felipe/Documentos/AMC/amc-project/play-scala-library/test/controllers/HomeControllerIntegrationSpec.scala:6: not found: type PlaySpecification
[error] class HomeControllerIntegrationSpec extends PlaySpecification {
```

These are my dependencies >

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  ws,
  evolutions,
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "anorm" % "2.4.0",
  "commons-codec" % "commons-codec" % "1.6",
  "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "1.5.1" % Test
)

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two frameworks for testing in play available, [specs2](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/) and [scalatest](http://www.scalatest.org/). You only need to use one though, not both. In your case things got a bit mixed up:

[`PlaySpecification`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.1/api/scala/index.html#play.api.test.PlaySpecification) is a trait for testing with specs2. However your dependencies contain only scalatestplus (and hence scalatest transitively) which means you're using scalatest to run your tests. In this case you want to use [`PlaySpec`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.1/api/scala/index.html#org.scalatestplus.play.PlaySpec) instead, that's the base class for scalatest suites.

Alternatively you can of course switch to specs2 instead, including it's dependency makes `PlaySpecification` available. Just add `specs2 % Test` to your dependencies in this case (and best remove scalatestplus).